# Flash Session não funciona, Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, laravel-5

Eu já fiz várias vezes isto mas por alguma razão agora não está a funcionar, não consigo agarrar o flash da sessão na view

UsersController:

```
public function login_page(Request $request) {

    $title = "login";

    $dataToView = array(
        "title" => $title,
    );

    return view('layouts/user_login', $dataToView);
}

public function doLogin(Request $request) {

    $credentials = array(
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    );

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        Session::flash('flash_error', 'Something went wrong with your login');
        return redirect(Session::get('lang'). '/user/login');
    }

    Session::flash('flash_success', 'You have logged in successfully ' .Auth::user()->name);

    return redirect(Session::get('lang'). '/user/login');
}
```

user_login.blade.php

```
div id="content">
<form method="POST" action="{{url($varNavBar['langLink']. '/user/login')}}">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>

@if(Session::has('flash_success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <b>{{Session::get('flash_success')}}</b>
    </div>
@elseif(Session::has('flash_error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <b>{{Session::get('flash_error')}}</b>
    </div>
@endif
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('en/user/login', 'UsersController@login_page');
Route::post('en/user/login', 'UsersController@doLogin');
```

Consigo resolver isto com `Session::set...` e `Session::pull...`. Mas gostava de saber o porquê de não estar a conseguir agarrar o flash na view

Comment: Acho que pode ser sua rota interferindo nisso.

Answer (score 1):

Eu gosto de fazer assim:

### routes.php

`Route::controller('en/user/login', 'UsersController');`

### UsersController.php

```
# Alterei aqui para Index, que é a primeira página a sera acessada quando acessa a URL padrão.

public function getIndex(Request $request) {

    $title = "login";

    $dataToView = array(
        "title" => $title,
    );

    return view('layouts/user_login', $dataToView);
}

# Aqui coloquei o `post` e alterei o nome da página para a qual aparece no <form>.

public function postLogin(Request $request) {

    $credentials = array(
        'email' => $request->input('email'),
        'password' => $request->input('password'),
    );

    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        Session::flash('flash_error', 'Something went wrong with your login');
        return redirect(Session::get('lang'). '/user/login');
    }

    Session::flash('flash_success', 'You have logged in successfully ' .Auth::user()->name);

    return redirect(Session::get('lang'). '/user/login');
}
```

Comment: Essa não é a solução, como eu acima menciono, consigo fazer isso dessa maneira... Com o set no controller em vez de flash. Esta solução serve para não imprimir as tags de HTML a partir do controller, ex:  no controller há uma `$var = <b>hey</b>` se mandar para a view, o output de `{{$var}}` é "<b>hey</b>" quando na realidade queremos `{!!$var!!}` que é "**hey**"

Comment: Está tudo ok, nunca precisei de mexer nesse ficheiro para fazer o flash... Algo me diz que algures a meio estou a fazer outro request e esse flash é perdido. Mas não vejo onde